# Why is my customed `::swap` function not called?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Here I write a code snippet to see which `swap` would be called, but the result is neither. Nothing is outputted.

```
#include<iostream>
class Test {};
void swap(const Test&lhs,const Test&rhs)
{
    std::cout << "1";
}

namespace std
{
    template<>
    void swap(const Test&lhs, const Test&rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "2";
    }
    /* If I remove the const specifier,then this will be called,but still not the one in global namespace,why?
    template<>
    void swap(Test&lhs, Test&rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "2";
    }
    */
}
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    Test a, b;
    swap(a, b);//Nothing outputed
    return 0;
}
```

Which `swap` is called? And in another circumstance, why is the specialized `swap` without `const` specifier called, not the `::swap`?

Comment: What do you mean by "Which swap is called on earth?"

Comment: @Bigiansen Because nothing is outputed.

Comment: @Ron The **Effective C++** by scott says it's ok to name `std` and provide your own specializaion.And I use `using namespace std` here to test what will happen.

Comment: @bigxiao At some level down the line, yes. Just not currently.

Comment: @bigxiao That means you need to say `using std::swap;`.

Comment: This code does not even compile because there is no `std::swap` template declaration available and function signatures do not match `std::swap`. [If you fix it then it would print 1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hBokJSRlVj2fkEFQ).

Comment: @Ron It's perfectly fine to add your own specialisations of `std`-defined functions.

Comment: @VTT I compiled it on VS2015,there's no warning.

Comment: @Angew I agree. I just feel currently it introduces more confusion for the OP than it does good.

Comment: @Ron No, it does not. They are actually trying to specialise `std::swap`, so they have no other option, really.

Comment: @VTT It also compiles with GCC 5. Remember that `<iostream>` is allowed to include additional headers, and also that not all implementations, especially older ones, reject `std::swap<const Test>` in the signature itself.

Comment: Side note: What is the intention of swapping? Is it meaningful at all to have const parameters?

Comment: @Aconcagua Well,it may be not appropriate to name `swap` here,I use it to test what will happen in this condition,not really want to `swap` them.

Comment: @VTT So is that because the user-provided is preferred  compared with the most specialized one?And why do we need the `utility` header?

Comment: @bigxiao It is found using ADL. `utility` is required because it is where `swap` template is declared.

Comment: @bigxiao It remains an interesting question, *but*: Either a function *shall* modify an object provided, or it won't. Having two overloads, one doing so, the other not, is a strong hint that one of them is badly named...

Comment: The program can compile with `c++03` standard, but not with `c++11` or afterwards. See https://godbolt.org/g/58JSLJ on compiler explorer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`std::swap()` is something like [[ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)]

```
template< class T >
void swap( T& a, T& b );
```

It is a better match than your

```
void swap(const Test& lhs, const Test& rhs);
```

for

```
swap(a, b);
```

where `a` and `b` are ***non-const***. So `std::swap()` is called, which outputs nothing.

Note that `std::swap()` participates in overload resolution because of `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Why is `void swap( T& a, T& b );` a better match?I thought the specialized one is prefered.

Comment: @bigxiao the most specialized one that most closely matches your variables is preferred. The most specialized match for your variables IS the non-const version, because your variables are also non-const.